# How does Fomorian Evil Eye work?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

On p. 136 of the *Monster Manual,* **Evil Eye** is an Action that applies damage (or half on a failed Charisma save).  The next entry in Actions is the **Curse of the Evil Eye**, which says:

> With a stare, the fomorian uses Evil Eye, but on a failed
> save, the creature is also cursed with magical deformities.
> While deformed, the creature has its speed halved and has
> disadvantage on ability checks, saving throws, and attacks
> based on Strength or Dexterity.

Does the Curse of the Evil Eye apply when the Evil Eye saving throw is failed, or does it require a separate Action to apply?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Curse of the Evil Eye** is a separate Action and must be used on its own. It does not happen when only **Evil Eye** is used.

What **Curse of the Evil Eye** does is the effect of **Evil Eye**, *plus* extra effects on a failed save.

Isn't that strictly better than just using **Evil Eye** then, though? Yes, but it's a recharge power that can only be used once in a fight, so that's not odd.